# How to get SSHHook to connect on airflow with a ssh_conn_id

Tags: python, ssh, airflow

I am trying to get a sftp connection via SSHHook on an airflow task, but the connection fails because of the `ssh_conn_id`. In the airflow logs, I get an error saying:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I tried creating a SSHHook object in a terminal shell using:

```
SSHHook(ssh_conn_id=<airflow_connection_name>, remote_host=<host>, 
        username=<username>, password=<password>)
```

and the error I got was SQL related:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: connection
[SQL: SELECT connection.password AS connection_password, connection.extra AS connection_extra, connection.id AS connection_id, connection.conn_id AS connection_conn_id, connection.conn_type AS connection_conn_type, connection.description AS connection_description, connection.host AS connection_host, connection.schema AS connection_schema, connection.login AS connection_login, connection.port AS connection_port, connection.is_encrypted AS connection_is_encrypted, connection.is_extra_encrypted AS connection_is_extra_encrypted
FROM connection
WHERE connection.conn_id = ?
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
[parameters: (<airflow_connection_name>, 1, 0)]
```

However, if I run the same code without a `ssh_conn_id`, i.e. `SSHHook(ssh_conn_id= remote_host=<host>, username=<username>, password=<password>)`, the host connects. I also tried hardcoding in a SSHHook with the same info in my dag file, and it connected successfully, but this is not going to fly since the password is present in the code. Does anyone know why airflow will not work with this `ssh_conn_id` and how I can get it to work with my ID?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just run the hook without having the "airflow" environment set. Running hook in terminal will simply not work unless you configure the environment properly. Hooks are note even supposed be run "standalone".

In this cae the https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#sql-alchemy-conn is not set and you are trying to access default empty sqlite database instead of the database you have set for Airflow.

There is no ready-recipe for running python code in terminal. But If you REALLY want to do it, you need to run `from airflow import settings` first and make sure before that `AIRFLOW_HOME` is set the same way as for your Airflow installation. That should likely configure the environment the same way as the airflow you use.